# What's the translation of an "egg crate mattress topper" in French?

Tags: traduction

A mattress topper [is](https://casper.com/blog/what-is-a-mattress-topper/):

> a two- to four-inch layer of memory foam, latex, or other material added on top of your mattress.

Egg crate means has the shape similar to an [egg crate](https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=egg+carton+drawing&asset_id=395952207):

[image]

[Example of an egg crate mattress topper](https://www.homedepot.com/pep/Mellow-3-in-Short-Queen-Egg-Crate-Memory-Foam-Mattress-Topper-with-Lavender-Infusion-HD-ECMF-03SQL/320656792?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-HDH-GGL-D59H-059_013_TEXTILES-NA-Multi-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-011_MATTRESS_TOPPERS_SS&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-HDH-GGL-D59H-059_013_TEXTILES-NA-Multi-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-011_MATTRESS_TOPPERS_SS-71700000086278730-58700007370547828-92700065995066629&gclid=Cj0KCQiApKagBhC1ARIsAFc7Mc7as4sejLA8I_6GsD9pXFH-pcfyDL54l8ui_ZVawSuQfef4pw-_91caAizWEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds):

[image]

Sometimes one just says "[egg crate](https://www.target.com/s/full+size+egg+crate)" to mean "egg crate mattress topper"

I believe mattress topper can be translated with "surmatelas en mousse". However, how can I translate the "egg crate" part? [DeepL suggests](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/egg%20crate%20mattress%20topper):

1. surmatelas en forme de caisse d'œufs
2. sur-matelas en forme de caisse d'oeufs
3. sur-matelas en forme de caisse à œufs

but I see just a few webpages containing that phrases, which makes me wonder whether a better translation exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une possibilité :

> Surmatelas en mousse *alvéolée*. [ [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=EGG%20CRATE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/18957587/coussin-alveole) ; « [honeycombed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alv%C3%A9ol%C3%A9) » :
> des œufs un peu [différents](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/alv%C3%A9ole/2631)... ]

Comment: ou structure en "nid d'abeille"

Comment: Quand j'ai assez de matière, j'ajoute ma propre réponse mais là ça me semblait un peu léger et assez proche de ta réponse.

Comment: Ce l'est assurément et je comprends ton opinion, mais avec le temps je pense un peu différemment. Ce n'est pas tant le mot _nid d'abeille_ qui diffère, de comment tu pourrais présenter ça ou formuler ça, et le fait d'avoir le nom d'un contributeur différent en tête de liste de la vue active fait que ça pique la curiosité et augmente les clics etc. Mais tu es bien libre... Indépendamment, la pire chose qu'on peut avoir sur ce genre de site c'est une réponse unique qui s'abreuve de multiples suggestions/précisions en commentaire, une mosaïque de multiples réponses vaut mieux à mon avis. @XouDo